# Hiding View after async call to the server completed

Tags: android-layout, visibility, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to have a preloader to show while my request to the server is waiting for response

but when I try to hide the preloader with `setVisibility(View.GONE);` it doesn't hide (even though the other content does get visible)

when I run the function that suppose to remove the preloader and show the other content directly (not in the callback of the async request - it works)

my layout looks like this (I removed all the irrelevant stuff like the `android:text` properties etc.):

[notice that the loader I'm using is a custom view I made (I don't know if it has anything to do with the problem]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

 <views.Loader
        android:id="@+id/preloader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsArea"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/my_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/my_dance"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/another_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

notice that the loader I'm using is a custom view (I don't know if it has anything to do with the problem)

My Java code is:

```
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_page);
            init();
    setLoading(true);
    loadData();
}

private void init(){
    preloader = (Loader) findViewById(R.id.preloader);
    buttonsArea= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonsArea);
}


private void loadData(){
    app.getManager().app_init(new OnAppInfoResponse(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(boolean success) {
            //this method runs on UI Thread through Handler
            setLoading(false);
        }
    });
}

private void setLoading(boolean loading) {
    this.loading = loading;
    if(loading){
        buttonsArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        preloader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        buttonsArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        preloader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Edit:

even weirder:
when I remove the `buttonsArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` line, the preloader does get hidden!

Thank you very much!!

Comment: currently I solved the problem by adding another `LinearLayout` to wrap the Loader but this seems to me like a bad way of implementing this